# Warning explode() in a map widget

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, explode

I am getting an error message on a page that is using a map widget from a certain plugin:

```
Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in 
        /usr/www/users/mednukptke/wordpress/wp-content/themes/jobify/inc/integrations/wp-job-manager/widgets/class-widget-jobs-map.php on line 111

Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in 
/usr/www/users/mednukptke/wordpress/wp-content/themes/jobify/inc/integrations/wp-job-manager/widgets/class-widget-jobs-map.php on line 111
```

I opened that specific file, line 111 reads

```
$center = isset( $instance[ 'center' ] ) && '' != $instance[ 'center' ] ? array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $instance[ 'center' ] ) ) : 'autofit';
```

Can anyone please tell me what I need to change to get rid of that error message?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `$instance['center']`?

Comment: The error is clear, isn't it: `explode` needs a string but you are putting an array into it.

Comment: Please include more code from above line 111.